# Parent class in unsorted property grid

Tags: c#, sorting, inheritance, propertygrid

I have a `PropertyGrid`, unsorted.

One object is an object that inherits from another class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class ExpandValues: Values
{
    public double Value2 { get; set; }

    public ExpandValues()
        : base()
    {

    }
    public ExpandValues(string name, double value1, double value2)
        : base(name, value1)
    {
        Value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

Parent class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Values
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public Values()
        : this(null, 0)
    {

    }
    public Values(string name, double value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;

    }
}
```

When I open the object that contains the class `ExpandValues` is showing me the values ​​like this:

```
Value2
Value
```

Is there a way for me to tell him first display the objects of the parent class (without making the PropertyGrid sorted?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the values ​​to be in order, I override the variable `value` of parent class:

I added a virtual to a variable in parent class:

```
public virtual double Value { get; set; }
```

Then I override him:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class ExpandValues: Values
{
    public override double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public double Value2 { get; set; }

    public ExpandValues()
        : base()
    {

    }
    public ExpandValues(string name, double value1, double value2)
        : base(name, value1)
    {
        Value2 = value2;
    }
}
```